# Node JS and Coinbase

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

I am trying to integrate Coinbase with Node Js, but I am unable to execute the code given on the tutorial page. My code is

```
`var coinbase = require('coinbase');
var client   = new coinbase.Client({'apiKey': mykey, 'apiSecret': mysecret});

client.getAccounts({}, function(err, accounts) {
  accounts.forEach(function(acct) {
    console.log('my bal: ' + acct.balance.amount + ' for ' + acct.name);
  });
});`
```

I get t the following error:

> accounts.forEach(account => {
>            ^
>   typeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
>   Looking forward to your answer! Thanks!

Comment: Add `if(err) { console.log(err); }` before the `foreach` loop to debug the error.

Comment: Thank you. I get a ReferenceError: err is not defined

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear: `accounts` is equal to null. You should check what's in `err` before working with `accounts`

Comment: Thank you, I am having difficulties also with checkng err. I get a reference error asaying that err is not defined. How to get over it? Thank you.

Comment: Just before `accounts.forEach`, add `if(typeof err !== 'undefined'){console.log(err);}`

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use like this

```
client.getAccounts({}, function(err, accounts) {
  accounts.forEach(function(acct) {
    console.log(acct.name + ': ' + acct.balance.amount + ' ' + acct.id );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a different API keys and check if the keys are enabled.

```
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;

var client = new Client({
  'apiKey': 'API KEY',
  'apiSecret': 'API SECRET'
});

client.getAccounts({}, function (err, accounts) {
  accounts.data.forEach(function (acct) {
    console.log(acct.name + ': ' + acct.balance.amount + ' ' + acct.id);
  });
});
```

Also accounts returns a lot of information but we are looking at the data block. Please refer the Coinbase API v2 documentation for complete sample response of the getAccounts() call - https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?javascript#account-resource
Let us know if this works. Good luck!